# Union to already massive table vs. create new table

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012

I have a table that I use for creating reports using powerpivot in Excel. The table has 30 columns and ~2M rows, and because of this massive # of columns and rows, the excel file is already ~20MB (and yes, I use every single column in that table).

The business has asked to add a new data in the excel, which will add three new columns and ~1M rows. I'm worried about what that will do to my excel and impact to the size. Unfortunately I cannot use join because the existing table has a different hierarchy level

I was thinking of modifying the stored procedures of the existing table to union the table that includes new data instead of pulling the new table to excel and create join within the powerpivot data model.

what's the "better" approach here? will the excel be smaller if I did a join within excel or have union within SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is - don't feed Excel with massive union-style tables in order to do a pivot queries.

There are [OLAP Cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube)s for exactly that purpose already invented. Excel can connect to this kind of datasource since quite some time.

In order to create the cube using Microsoft's SQL server take a look at [Analysis Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Analysis_Services). The name had changed several times and other DB providers also have this kind of support.

Basic concept is the same. Pump your data into an efficient normalized cross-indexed structure. Use Excel and other tools to analyze that structure.

The drawback is that you will not see the data "online" and in case of Microsoft's SQL you need to purchase special license to be able to use it.